# OpenSSL verify fails, certificate is installed locally

Tags: windows, openssl, imap, ca, self-signed-certificate

Our IMAP connection to a Exchange Server fails because the certificate validation with openssl fails.

The client which initiates the connection is a Windows Server 2019 Standard running openssl 64-bit.

> **C:\Users\Administrator>"C:\Program
> Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe" s_client -connect server:993
> -showcerts**
>
> CONNECTED(0000019C) Can't use SSL_get_servername depth=0 C = CH, ST = Z\C3\BCrich, L = Richterswil, O = Wisli Am See, OU = Informatik, CN = server.ch verify
> **error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate verify return:1**
> depth=0 C = CH, ST = Z\C3\BCrich, L = Richterswil, O = Wisli Am See,
> OU = Informatik, CN = server.ch verify
> error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate verify return:1
> depth=0 C = CH, ST = Z\C3\BCrich, L = Richterswil, O = Wisli Am See,
> OU = Informatik, CN = server.ch verify return:1
> --- Certificate chain  0 s:C = CH, ST = Z\C3\BCrich, L = Richterswil, O = Wisli Am See, OU = Informatik, CN = server.ch
> i:DC = ch, DC = wisliamsee, DC = int, CN = int-wisliamsee-CA
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIHfjCCBWagAwIBAgITRAAAABOtj2lO7OjyhQAAAAAAEzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF
> ADBhMRIwEAYKCZImiZPyLGQBGRYCY2gxGjAYBgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFgp3aXNsaWFt
> c2VlMRMwEQYKCZImiZPyLGQBGRYDaW50MRowGAYDVQQDExFpbnQtd2lzbGlhbXNl
> ZS1DQTAeFw0yMTEyMDExNjA2NTVaFw0yMzEyMDExNjE2NTVaMIGHMQswCQYDVQQG
> EwJDSDEQMA4GA1UECAwHWsO8cmljaDEUMBIGA1UEBxMLUmljaHRlcnN3aWwxFTAT
> BgNVBAoTDFdpc2xpIEFtIFNlZTETMBEGA1UECxMKSW5mb3JtYXRpazEkMCIGA1UE
> AxMbd3N2cy1leDAyLmludC53aXNsaWFtc2VlLmNoMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEF
> AAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAunATwbhbdBelKgwlPHY75mlfhbt4ZMQiLG6SGYB/TKRx
> JKq3qw8AJ7XUUpmrmHglxglIxE77IFox1gC2HH6oVII5NiBEflQUBbMdlQSNQjdy
> LmosXfy5cCNouAbN7pJ2obf8JknTu6WLq7JLKVSOQga+gwb1ELMiGG5wNxFKDOss
> QEZNc8qGypsU59bysakaF2q9fyuJxkv2c4/5I1ZxgiC1hyBfM9YyWZ3mexRhvXms
> m6ivHVEOoXCMXIi5a9zaQCMQuxIgdWdnUrDXpcmST0NR33L41Imlu9CBKFw/mTs6
> VMKQclve/q4NB7eDHy0f4NYibd8uAPIWB9VDsaKLRQIDAQABo4IDBjCCAwIwDgYD
> VR0PAQH/BAQDAgWgMB0GA1UdDgQWBBRO0u6e11CokEqvcpZ0II89BtpWWTCBkQYD
> VR0RBIGJMIGGght3c3ZzLWV4MDIuaW50Lndpc2xpYW1zZWUuY2iCHkF1dG9EaXNj
> b3Zlci5pbnQud2lzbGlhbXNlZS5jaIIaQXV0b0Rpc2NvdmVyLndpc2xpYW1zZWUu
> Y2iCCVdTVlMtRVgwMoIRaW50Lndpc2xpYW1zZWUuY2iCDXdpc2xpYW1zZWUuY2gw
> HwYDVR0jBBgwFoAU9oAHGV2Kkbn6WuLzv6a5074iV1cwgdoGA1UdHwSB0jCBzzCB
> zKCByaCBxoaBw2xkYXA6Ly8vQ049aW50LXdpc2xpYW1zZWUtQ0EsQ049V1NWUy1X
> VTAxLENOPUNEUCxDTj1QdWJsaWMlMjBLZXklMjBTZXJ2aWNlcyxDTj1TZXJ2aWNl
> cyxDTj1Db25maWd1cmF0aW9uLERDPWludCxEQz13aXNsaWFtc2VlLERDPWNoP2Nl
> cnRpZmljYXRlUmV2b2NhdGlvbkxpc3Q/YmFzZT9vYmplY3RDbGFzcz1jUkxEaXN0
> cmlidXRpb25Qb2ludDCBzAYIKwYBBQUHAQEEgb8wgbwwgbkGCCsGAQUFBzAChoGs
> bGRhcDovLy9DTj1pbnQtd2lzbGlhbXNlZS1DQSxDTj1BSUEsQ049UHVibGljJTIw
> S2V5JTIwU2VydmljZXMsQ049U2VydmljZXMsQ049Q29uZmlndXJhdGlvbixEQz1p
> bnQsREM9d2lzbGlhbXNlZSxEQz1jaD9jQUNlcnRpZmljYXRlP2Jhc2U/b2JqZWN0
> Q2xhc3M9Y2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbkF1dGhvcml0eTA+BgkrBgEEAYI3FQcEMTAvBicr
> BgEEAYI3FQiEkdoGhuCIcIGFmSSEk70zgcOAe4Fph5XfS4TP3icCAWQCAQUwEwYD
> VR0lBAwwCgYIKwYBBQUHAwEwGwYJKwYBBAGCNxUKBA4wDDAKBggrBgEFBQcDATAN
> BgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAgEAeW3UJ0B40Y0GG0D1+v/h5K2rLLjdQ/THYqYsIz4N
> 0m/S1ijiKVrJg6tD5sOD+mhoGr/RQTOPJzHow7auhf3LoZ/QDengunxZ+02/zTdM
> p3rxutwGr6vpmZ8Xqm3n5pJPKnFDQt3vtc7VbBuX7yzq2yIt9UMpf9SC0HGsiL3T
> zDp6LyDVunM79HaFuCLOX8qMFm9aMxJbCwEwEPrQFI4r9xqcOpszayQxZi07AmOs
> eoch+RyjWqKzoD50tXjHnGRa7rkP4qbtf48jqc9kdjt/Ci2/SN59RCMEFXbmTF8V
> MqxQ6MvSAbClIGXzd5TfuPMKrSazAacNtjkpjMFDAslurpkQKTim918op2BAcLJH
> kcgVXlEVBXvTPDJM0Z7UsuuMq+vy2dEjjoD5CmPmHDXJnnr9d5OQVZaS7QIKQV+K
> 0IKfmb3i8WroRbnJFgxF26Kr5T3BW32kRHOQSVDpFqiaadY01j+nHMMbKv3YQDGb
> VplhxLHZhi+rI8jynRKkMVrbfKR/FgvMQvtpDMJ7WRcV6j3lLdaqWg9z3w1iR2ta
> 45mouk+J2n4DMOJosyWIcdF84eebGSucmu5SoFkKEXZV+OWmAe2p/wdmTN5pvGfy
> e4OBXeC8XRnY6BdR0Qgg8bk1r4u4Bly/ITn1c+p1LQKMVdqCSWSAcBmAyIAFM7zG SNo=
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>
> --- Server certificate subject=C = CH, ST = Z\C3\BCrich, L = Richterswil, O = Wisli Am See, OU = Informatik, CN =
> server.ch
>
> issuer=DC = ch, DC = wisliamsee, DC = int, CN = int-wisliamsee-CA
>
> No client certificate CA names sent Peer signing digest: SHA256 Peer signature type: RSA Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-384, 384 bits
> --- SSL handshake has read 2442 bytes and written 451 bytes Verification error: unable to verify the first certificate
> --- New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 Server public key is 2048 bit Secure Renegotiation IS supported Compression: NONE
> Expansion: NONE No ALPN negotiated SSL-Session:
> Protocol  : TLSv1.2
> Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
> Session-ID: 7C3500005C092BAF384569A2EF61EE37099BF0158441A5F09B81C878B2E2971E
> Session-ID-ctx:
> Master-Key: B226822F9899A655C27521A76F8E952B5E81F048E375F3ACC021D983868DB98DF8A571256B97533765A9C9A7F40BB7E6
> PSK identity: None
> PSK identity hint: None
> SRP username: None
> Start Time: 1666602175
> Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
> **Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)**
> Extended master secret: yes
>
> - OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.

Both the self signed CA and the server certificate are installed in computer certificate:
[Windows Computer Certificates, installed selfsigned root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Bap.png)

[Server certificate including root installed in Trusted Publishers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPkqF.png)

I have tried to delete all existing certificates related to the server in the store, then get the certificate via openssl(with -connect and -showcerts) and save it again to make sure there is no old or faulty certificate in the store. Same result. I also tried to get the certificate again from the target server again and reinstall it, same result.

Why does it return code 21 even though the certificate is in trusted root certificates?

Comment: I re-requested a new certificate from CA without umlauts because I heard this can lead to problems but same result. I install certificate to local store, error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate verify return:1

Comment: This isn't programming or development, but OpenSSL doesn't use the Windows certificate store, it only uses a _file_ or a directory of hash-named files (both in PEM). You appear to be using the ShiningLight build, in which case the default file or dir are in `%programfiles%\common files\SSL`; you can check with `openssl version -d`. In modern Windows hand-modifying things under `%programfiles%` (or its x86 variant) may not work reliably; instead specify what you want with options on the command line (`-CAfile` and/or `-CApath`) or set envvars `SSL_CERT_FILE` and/or `SSL_CERT_DIR`.